# Collision detection in platformer, how to fix my character sliding off the edges of platforms?

Tags: flutter, flame

The character/player in my game will slowly slide off platforms once he is near the edge. How would I fix this? Ideally my character would remain on top of a platform even in a situation like this:[image]

My Player class (onCollision method being the relevant part):

```
class Player extends SpriteAnimationGroupComponent with HasGameRef<Gain>, KeyboardHandler, CollisionCallbacks {
  String character;
  Player({pos, this.character = "Ninja Frog"}) : super(position: pos);

  final double stepTime = 0.05;

  ...
  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    if (other is Platform) {
      if (intersectionPoints.length == 2) {
        Vector2 mid = (intersectionPoints.elementAt(0) + intersectionPoints.elementAt(1)) / 2;
        Vector2 collisionNormal = absoluteCenter - mid;
        final seperationDist = (size.x / 2) - collisionNormal.length;
        collisionNormal.normalize();
        if (Vector2(0, -1).dot(collisionNormal) > 0.9) {
          _isOnGround = true;
        }
        position += collisionNormal.scaled(seperationDist);
      }
    }
    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
  }
}
```

My Platform class that represents walls, ground, ceiling of game:

```
class Platform extends PositionComponent with CollisionCallbacks {
  bool canJumpThrough;
  Platform({required Vector2 position, required Vector2 size, this.canJumpThrough = false}) : super(position: position, size: size);

  @override
  FutureOr<void> onLoad() {
    add(RectangleHitbox(collisionType: CollisionType.passive));
    return super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this, one way is to change to `onCollisionStart` instead of `onCollision`. Since `onCollisionStart` is only called once the collision begins you should keep the player and the platform overlapping with one pixel, and then once the player has moved off the platform `onCollisionEnd` will be called, and you can reactivate things like gravity.

The `onCollision` method you are using now will be called in each tick and there are probably some rounding errors that make the player slide.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem in my game. For me it was the fact that I was using a circle hitbox for my player. Changing it to a rectangle hitbox worked but now it's not working well with the collision code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).